# why js cannot be executed directly by browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I know my question is naive and may be funny for some. 
I know how to execute js in browser using html files.

But if I have a file:
example.js

```
 const posts = [{"title":"post1"},
    {"title":"post2"}]


   function getPosts()
    {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            posts.forEach((post)=>
            {
                let output = post;
            }
        )
          document.body.innerHTML(output);
        },3000)
    }

    getPosts();
```

If I open file in browser (as we do with html files) why i see code instead of output?
I am trying to clear few concepts here. Because as per my knowledge browser has engines to compile js then why it did not compile js?

Comment: Well, one problem is `getPosts()
{` is not how you define a (standalone) function, nor is `function getPosts();` how you invoke a function. Also, `let` has block scope, not global scope.

Comment: How do you "run it in browser"?

Comment: What does "run it in browser" mean exactly? Execute in console, include via `<script>`-tag, anything else?

Comment: Just by opening file in browser as we do with html files?

Comment: You need to move the function keyword up to the first getPosts - it does not belong where you put it. Then you can run it in the console. Hit F12, console and past the code in front of the `>`  -  except your output is out of scop due to the `let`

Comment: Browsers open web pages. You need plugins to run .js files seperately. But just make a simple html page and include the script there. If you don't include the script inside a valid HTML file, there isn't even a body to set the innerHTML.

Comment: If you wrap the code in `<html><head><script>....</script></head><body></body>` you can open the file in the browser because then it is HTML

Comment: Because Browsers are HTML renderers. JS and CSS are just sidefeatures

Comment: And you probably see the code because the browser interprets your .js file as a basic text file and hence, shows the code instead of execute it.

Comment: But the script must be in the head or it will be cleared when the innerHTML is replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit a URL that returns JavaScript, a browser will render its source code as text.

It doesn't execute it because none of the browser authors have considered *execute the JavaScript* to be a more useful result.

When JavaScript was first introduced, it was designed to use an existing DOM as its main I/O system. Browsers still expect JS loaded from the WWW to work that way.

Comment: Thanks. But it is very confusing when we put it in script tag it starts giving output. Else it returns source code.

Comment: How is it confusing? The script tag is inside a .html file. It's two different files, with a different extension. In browsers, Javascript helps you do things to HTML pages, so I find it very logical that if there is no HTML page, javascript won't do anything. Compare it to a traffic light in a corn field. If there's no road, there's no need for a traffic light. These days javascript can do more than just help web pages, but that doesn't matter to browsers.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks a lot, now much clear. Thanks for taking time out to explain.